# How to insert mulitple POST value from array using PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my code when i ECHO out its show all POST array , but when mysqli_query action run it only insert the last value. How to insert all data in query? Can anyone help me please...

```
$ser = $_POST['serial'];
foreach ($ser as $seria) {
    echo $serial = $seria;
}

$re = $_POST['ref_no'];
foreach ($re as $refe) {
    echo $ref = $refe;
}

$des = $_POST['desc'];  
foreach ($des as $desce) {
    echo $desc = $desce;
}

$uni = $_POST['unitss'];
foreach ($uni as $units) {
    echo $unit = $units;
}

$qt = $_POST['qty'];
foreach ($qt as $qtys) {
    echo $qty = $qtys;
}

$pric = $_POST['price'];
foreach ($pric as $prices) {
    echo $price = $prices;
}

$amoun = $_POST['amount'];
foreach ($amoun as $amounts) {
    echo $amount = $amounts;
}

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT into purchase_order (po_id, po_no, serial_no, ref_no, description, unit, qty, price, amount, status) VALUES ('', '".$po_nom."', '".$mr_no."', '".$serial."', '".$ref."', '".$desc."', '".$unit."', '".$qty."', '".$price."', '".$amount."', 'Pending')");
```

Comment: What is your form structure?

Comment: this is not the right approach to do your task...you can print every thing but can insert one thing only because u are trying to insert last value of loop..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$ser = $_POST['serial'];
foreach($ser as $keys=>$vals){
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT into purchase_order (po_id, serial_no, ref_no, description, unit, qty, price, amount, status) VALUES ('', '".$vals."', '".$_POST['ref'][$keys]."', '".$_POST['desc'][$keys]."', '".$_POST['unitss'][$keys]."', '".$_POST['qty'][$keys]."', '".$_POST['price'][$keys]."', '".$_POST['amount'][$keys]."', 'Pending')");
}
```

or you can also do this

```
$ser = $_POST['serial'];
foreach($ser as $keys=>$vals){
$values_array[]="('', '".$vals."', '".$_POST['ref'][$keys]."', '".$_POST['desc'][$keys]."', '".$_POST['unitss'][$keys]."', '".$_POST['qty'][$keys]."', '".$_POST['price'][$keys]."', '".$_POST['amount'][$keys]."', 'Pending')";

}
$values=implode(",",$values_array);
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT into purchase_order (po_id, serial_no, ref_no, description, unit, qty, price, amount, status) VALUES ".$values." ");
```

Comment: It's highly inefficient to place queries inside loops, it results in a separate transaction call on the server for every instance in the loop.  The full string should be built in the loop and the query executed just once.

Answer (score 1):

there's quite a big assumption here that all the arrays have the same size:

```
$sql='';
$n=len($_POST['serial']);
for ($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) {
    $amount = $_POST['amount'][$i];
    $price = $_POST['price'][$i];
    $qty=$_POST['qty'][$i];
    $unit=$_POST['unitss'][$i];
    $desc=$_POST['desc'][$i];
    $ref=$_POST['ref_no'][$i];
    $serial=$_POST['serial'][$i];
    $sql_part="INSERT into purchase_order (po_id, po_no, serial_no, ref_no, description, unit, qty, price, amount, status) VALUES ('', '".$po_nom."', '".$mr_no."', '".$serial."', '".$ref."', '".$desc."', '".$unit."', '".$qty."', '".$price."', '".$amount."', 'Pending')";
    $sql=$sql.';'.$sql_part;
}
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

also, note that it is not a good practice to insert data to the db directly from the `$_POST` variables due to [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: I've never found a PHP lib that would accept multipart sql statements, in a single transaction, terminated with ; (admittedly, I never bothered with mysqli).  But still, why run multiple SQL statements when a single one will do?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$serial = $_POST['serial'];
$ref = $_POST['ref_no'];
$desc = $_POST['desc'];  
$unit = $_POST['unitss'];
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT into purchase_order (po_id, po_no, serial_no, ref_no, description, unit, qty, price, amount, status) VALUES ('', '".$po_nom."', '".$mr_no."', '".$serial."', '".$ref."', '".$desc."', '".$unit."', '".$qty."', '".$price."', '".$amount."', 'Pending')");
```

Comment: I believe this will result in some "incompatibility in converting type array to type string" message.  That the OP is using loops to echo out the values of each $_POST item infers that each $_POST value is an array it's self.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your echos show all the values is that they are each within the loop you are running to iterate through the arrays.  what you are doing is overwriting the value in each of your variables inside the loop each time it steps through it, echoing it out, and then overwriting it again with the next value in the array.

you will only be able to do what you are trying to do if all arrays are the same size, you will then need to build your query string within the loop, rather than after it.

I am unfamiliar with mysqli, so I'll give you an example using PDO (this is untested and isn't meant to just plug in to your code, it's simply supposed to make the logic and the process clearer):

```
$con= new PDO("mysql:host=<host>;dbname=<dbName>", "dbUsr", "dbPwd");
$sql = "INSERT INTO purchase_order (po_id, po_no, serial_no, ref_no, description, unit, qty, price, amount, status) VALUES";
$masterArray = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['serial']); $i++){
  $masterArray[] = array('serial=>$_POST['serial'], 'ref_no'=>$_POST['ref_no'], 'desc'=>$_POST['desc'], 'unitss'=>$_POST['unitss'], 'qty'=>$_POST['qty'], 'price'=>$_POST['price'], 'amount'=>$_POST['amount'])
  $sql .= "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,"Pending") ";
}
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$marker = 1;
foreach($masterArray as $idx=>$row){
  foreach($row as $title=>$value){
    $stmt->bindParam($marker, $value)
    $marker++;
  }
}
$stmt->execute();
```